# How to enable TLS1.2 on IIS7 Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, ssl, iis-7, server, tls1.2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 that serves services on IIS7. I enabled TLS 1.2 as you see below

[image]

But unfortunately, on of my client is said that they got SSL connection error using TLS 1.2. When I tried to check using OpenSSL, really there is a problem with TLS 1.2.

[image]

So, could you please help me, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You don't give your Windows version, but to my understanding IIS7 is [Windows Vista or Server2008 which do not support TLS 1.1 or 1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations#Protocol_support). If so, upgrade your Windows, or replace IIS with a webserver that uses a non-Windows SSL/TLS implementation e.g. apache. Also your title is comletely unrelated to your question.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thx for comment, what would be the title?

Comment: Your problem and question was enabling TLS1.2 on IIS7. It has nothing to do with Secure Renegotiation, which is a particular protocol feature in SSL/TLS, or any renegotiation at all, including the now-obsolete original SSL/TLS renegotiation now called for clarity Insecure Renegotiation. The output from `s_client` from the line beginning `New,` down, including the line about `Secure Renegotiation`, is meaningless for a failed handshake (except Verify Return Code which is meaningful in _some_ cases but not yours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS12)

> For TLS 1.2 to be enabled and negotiated on servers that run Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, you MUST create the "DisabledByDefault" entry in the
>   appropriate subkey (Client, Server) and set it to "0". The entry will
>   not be seen in the registry and it is set to "1" by default.

Comment: You can you provide a link to where that SubKey is?
Is it in the Registry? If so, what HIVE is it in?
(Assuming IIS7 has reg Hives like other Windows version)